# Identify the cursor position in different text area and insert text on selecting items in a listbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

can any one help me on this?

I got a .aspx page designed with two text area controls and a list box control.

```
<td>
    <p>Base Entity Attributes</p>
    <select name="drop1" id="SelectGroupApiS" size="4">
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <p>REQUEST XML</p>
    <textarea id="txtAreaRequest" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
</td>
<td>
    <p>RESPONSE XML</p>
    <textarea id="txtAreaResponse" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
</td>
```

And when I click on any listbox item I made the current text of listitem to be in TextArea using jquery. But I want the text to be in the textbox that contained the cursor position.
currently i made to be in single textbox. I want now the text to be displsyed in the one of the two text box that contains the cursor position.

How to do make it happened?

Help me plss

Comment: By "cursor position" i think you mean focus, right?!

Comment: I just now made the text of selected list item to be inserted in single textarea  as like $("#txtArea1").insertAtCaret($('#lis>option:selected').text());        But now i want it as if(txtArea1.gotfocus()){insert to txtare1} else if(txtArea2.gotfocus()){insert to txtarea 2}

Comment: @roasted the textbox that got the lastfocus needs the text inserted on clicking items in the listbox. And on pageload the focus has to be set to any one of textbox initially?

Comment: When you click on the list item, the textbox will anyway lose focus, i.e. something like `txtArea1.gotfocus()` won't work as it will not have focus anyway.

Comment: @techfoobar yeah You are right, I want the text inserted in current cursor location in any of text area. It now happens for single text box always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/LBkcV/

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <p>Base Entity Attributes</p>
    <select name="drop1" id="SelectGroupApiS" size="4">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <p>REQUEST XML</p>
    <textarea id="txtAreaRequest" class="tarea" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
</td>
<td>
    <p>RESPONSE XML</p>
    <textarea id="txtAreaResponse" class="tarea" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
</td>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var activeArea;
$(document).ready(function(){
    activeArea = $("#txtAreaRequest");
});
$(".tarea").click(function(){
    activeArea = $(this);
}).focus(function(){
    activeArea = $(this);
});

$("#SelectGroupApiS").change(function(){
    $(activeArea).append($("#SelectGroupApiS option:selected").val());    
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to have a handle to the textarea that last had focus and use this handle when clicking on the lsit item.

i.e. something like

```
var $focusTA = null;
$('textarea').focus(function() {
    $focusTA = $(this);
});
```

And do

```
$focusTA.insertAtCaret($('#lis>option:selected').text());
```

for setting the text.

Comment: Thanks for yous answer mate tried it but doesnt worked out. Anyhow thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly your question, you could do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('#txtAreaRequest').focus()});

var dataTB = [];
$('textarea').blur(function() {
    dataTB[0] = this;
    dataTB[1] = getCaret(this);
});

$('#SelectGroupApiS').change(function() {
    var valTB =  $(dataTB[0]).val();    $(dataTB[0]).val(valTB.substring(0,dataTB[1])+$('option:selected',this).text()+valTB.substring(dataTB[1]));

});



function getCaret(node) {
    if (node.selectionStart) {
        return node.selectionStart;
    } else if (!document.selection) {
        return 0;
    }

    var c = "\001",
        sel = document.selection.createRange(),
        dul = sel.duplicate(),
        len = 0;

    dul.moveToElementText(node);
    sel.text = c;
    len = dul.text.indexOf(c);
    sel.moveStart('character', -1);
    sel.text = "";
    return len;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mcDhE/